# Downloading Dailymotion videos on iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube, download

I'm trying to include a feature that allows the download of videos from a Dailymotion channel in an iOS app and i'ld like to know if there is a way or a library like [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser/blob/master/YoutubeParser/Classes/HCYoutubeParser.m) to get the url to the mp4 file of the video.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you are new to iOS dev.

Apple does not allow you or anyone to download the files/video from a third party service provider before the  third party acknowledgment.

Second you cannot link and open a Dailymotion/Youtube etc. channel into a app browser on iOS. you need to integrate the channels natively on your iOS App.

Read the Apple terms & conditions from the Apple developer website if you want to start creating an Apple iOS App.

Regards
Rajeev

Comment: Didn't knew Apple prohibited such thing.. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Please could you provide links to where you have read this to back this up with. This answer lacks any evidence and more opinionated then fact, if you could provide this evidence this would back your statement up more.